# Printing the number of char's by a randomly generated number in a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was wondering how to go about randomly generating a number, and then having it print that number as a character. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[][] ground = new int[12][12];
    int mineNum;

    System.out.print ("Please Enter an Integer");

    int num = scan.nextInt();

    if(num > -1 && num <145){
        for (int i=0; i<ground.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < ground[i].length;j++){
                ground[i][j] = mineNum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that you definitely have to have the random int stored in a variable. But from there I want to have the random int's that the user put in and translate that as X', and input those x's randomly into the array, so I would have to translate that number into number of char, and then insert it randomly into the array with another for? The idea is to look something like , for example, say mineNum is 5, it would look something like this once printed for a 3x9 grid.

0 0 0 0 X 0 X 0 0

0 0 X 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 X X 0 0 0

Comment: Why so few X's?

Comment: I was using it just as an example, say if the example grid is 3x9 and the random number generated was 5, then it would input 5 x's randomly into the grid

Comment: So something like `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) arr[rnd.nextInt(3)][rnd.nextInt(9)] = 'X';`

Comment: I actually asked the question wrong, i'm not supposed to be making a random integer, because the random integer is provided by the user

Comment: No, you asked the question correctly, I think.  The user's input is _not_ random because the user picks it.  That number, in turn, determines the number of random Xs which will be placed on the board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to generate 5 distinct random numbers within the dimensions of your 2D grid which would represent Xs.  Then fill everything else with Os.  I generate random numbers between 0 and `dim^2 - 1`.  Then I add them to a set until the desired number of random positions has been reached.  Finally, I convert those numbers to x/y dimensions to place the Xs onto the board.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int dim = 5;
char[][] ground = new char[dim][dim];
Set<Integer> xSet = new HashSet<>();

System.out.print ("Please Enter an Integer");
int mineNum = scan.nextInt();

Random rand = new Random();
while (xSet.size() < mineNum) {
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(dim*dim);
    xSet.add(randomNum);
}

// default everything to being Os
for (int r=0; r < dim; ++r) {
    for (int c=0; c < dim; ++c) {
        ground[r][c] = 'O';
    }
}

// then overwrite with Xs
for (int num : xSet) {
    int x = num % dim;
    int y = num / dim;
    ground[x][y] = 'X';
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ground).replace("], ", "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));

[O, O, O, O, O]
[O, O, O, X, X]
[O, O, X, O, O]
[O, O, X, O, O]
[O, O, O, X, O]
```

### Demo

Comment: I would avoid recreating `Random` in a loop.

Comment: I actually asked the question wrong, i'm not supposed to be making a random integer, because the random integer is provided by the user which is mineNum

Comment: @LexieAnne I don't think you understand my code at all.  I'm not "making" `mineNum` random, rather the number of Xs is a value _you_ determine when you enter it into the program.  Check the working demo to convince yourself.

Comment: Ah , I see. If you don't mind me asking, I just want to understand the code, is it the hashing that allows you to insert the number of ints?

Comment: Well I use a trick.  Java's `Random` class is really good at generating numbers within a _range_, say 0 to 25, for a 5x5 board, but we need xy coordinates.  So what I do is to convert that number into xy.  The mod gives the x value and the quotient gives the y value.  You could also generate x and y separately, but it's more work IMO.